# Where are Heroku CLI Plugins Stored?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I installed a Heroku plugin, and I'd like to tinker with the source code of the plugin easily, by directly editing the plugin JavaScript package. However, I don't know where plugins are stored. I skimmed the [heroku plugin docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/developing-cli-plugins) and didn't see an answer.

Where can I find the installed plugin on my machine? In my case, I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\$(user)\AppData\Local\heroku\plugins\

Comment: Thanks, but on macOS.